# ReferenceError: THREE is not defined in a Rails Project with the threejs-rails gem

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, three.js

I am working in a ruby on rails project with three.js. I installed the corresponding gem and it seems to work just fine. But somehow the javascript still throws the following Error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: THREE is not defined
```

on the Line:

```
renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
```

The weird thing is that my program seems to be working. My object gets displayed.

my javscript file looks like this:

```
// set size to the size of the containing box
var box = document.getElementById('player');
if(box){
    var boxSize = box.clientWidth;
}
var a = 0.05;
// set some camera attributes
var VIEW_ANGLE = 45,
ASPECT = 1,
NEAR = 0.1,
FAR = 10000;
var camera, scene, renderer;
var $player;
var char, materialChar ;
init();
animate();

function init() {
renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, 1, 0.1, 10000 );
camera.position.y = 10;
camera.position.z = 20;
scene = new THREE.Scene();
// get the DOM element to attach to
// - assume we've got jQuery to hand
$player = $('#player');
// attach the render-supplied DOM element
$player.append(renderer.domElement);
// create the character
initChar();
// create a point light
addLight();
scene.add(camera);
// draw!
renderer.setSize(boxSize, boxSize);
renderer.render(scene, camera);
renderer.shadowMap.enabled = true;
document.getElementById("player").addEventListener("click", zoom);
}

function addLight(){
var dirLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff, 1);
dirLight.position.set(100, 100, 50);
scene.add(dirLight);
var ambLight = new THREE.AmbientLight(0x404040);
scene.add(ambLight);
var bluePoint = new THREE.PointLight(0x0033ff, 3, 150);
bluePoint.position.set( 70, 5, 70 );
scene.add(bluePoint);
scene.add(new THREE.PointLightHelper(bluePoint, 3));
var greenPoint = new THREE.PointLight(0x33ff00, 1, 150);
greenPoint.position.set( -70, 5, 70 );
scene.add(greenPoint);
scene.add(new THREE.PointLightHelper(greenPoint, 3));
}

function initChar(){
var textureLoader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
var texture = textureLoader.load('<%= asset_path 'grey.jpg' %>');
materialChar = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
    map: texture
});
var loader = new THREE.JSONLoader();
loader.load('<%= asset_path 'standard-male-figure2.json' %>', function(geometry){
    char = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, materialChar );

    scene.add(char);
});
}

function animate(){
requestAnimationFrame( animate );
render();
}

function render(){
//char.rotation.y += 0.05;
renderer.render( scene, camera );
}

function zoom(){
    camera.position.z = camera.position.z - 10;
}
```

Comment: I would check if BVHLoader.js file is included after three.js. It may be better to use grunt or some other minifier and combine the Three.js file and any external add-ons such as the BVHLoader into a single three.min.js file of your own in the gem. But otherwise, I don't think there's enough here to answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

I have similar problem in Rails 4.2. I think the default jquery / Ajax gem is missing the following component. I have it linked in my erb which solved the problem. It can also be configured to precompile by using asset pipeline if you choose to.

```js
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/r79/three.min.js"></script>
```